# SsrsMsbuildTasks - adding images files to ssrs report deployment using AddResource task

Tags: msbuild, ssrs-2008

I've been using the excellent [ssrsmsbuildtasks](http://ssrsmsbuildtasks.codeplex.com/) for a couple years to automate ssrs report/folder/datasource deployment. Thumbs up.

On the current gig they have 'loose' image files that need to be deployed to the reports folder. Looks like the AddResource task should do this but I get the following error:

> Reporting error UploadResource: The method or operation is not
>   implemented.

I've posted to the codeplex project (not very active) [here](http://ssrsmsbuildtasks.codeplex.com/discussions/265046) and directly to Steve Wright's blog [here](http://zogamorph.blogspot.com/2006/12/delpoying-reporting-services-reports.html), but I have little sense of delayed gratification.

I'm using the following msbuild script to try and upload the file:

```
<Target Name="AddResources" DependsOnTargets="GetServerUrl">
    <AddResource ReportServerURL="$(TargetServerUrl)" Folder="$(TargetReportFolder)" Files="c:\temp\CHSLogo.gif" />
</Target>
```

I looked at the sources and AddResource task is calling CreateCatalogItem (ItemType "Resource") on the ReportService2010.asmx API. I don't know enough about the ssrs api to know if this is what I'm looking for.

Even if you don't get an answer... I hope to raise awareness regarding [ssrsmsbuildtasks](http://ssrsmsbuildtasks.codeplex.com/) as they are a great way to automate report deployment!

/jhd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author had an unintended NotImplementedException in AddResource. He corrected and published a new build 7/18/2011. I have downloaded, tested, verified. Works great. See [discussion thread on codeplex](http://ssrsmsbuildtasks.codeplex.com/discussions/265046) for details.

Again, if are looking to automate SSRS report deployment you should really have a look at ssrsmsbuildtasks. I've been using them for several years and you have have your report deployment up and running in no time. Good examples and obviously good support.

Good stuff.